# Froala editor set default font size for p tags

Tags: froala

When the froala editor is initialised on the page and i start typing and inspect the html, no inline styles (font-size) are being applied to the paragraph tags.

I want to be able to have a default font-size applied the `<p>` tags

Ive tried adding: `fontSizeDefaultSelection: '30'` but it doesnt set any default font-size by default.

Ive also tried calling this method on initialisation:

```
'initialized': function () {
    this.fontSize.apply('32px')
}
```

When calling the above method i get this error in the console:

```
froala_editor.pkgd.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tagName')
```